# tensortrade.environments NOT being recognized or detected by VS Code IDE

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, forex

I am making a simple Reinforcement Learning based Forex Trading Bot.
I have the following code:

```
from tensortrade import environments as te
from tensortrade.environments import forex as tfx
```

In the above code "tensortrade.environments" gets a yellow swiggy line underneath it in VS Code. Which means it is not being detected. I have troubleshooted it everything is okay. I have installed the latest versions of TensorTrade and TensorFlow libraries. And every other thing is fine. It seems that I missing an important update about TensorTrade. I get the following error upon running the code while this piece "tensortrade.environments" is not being recognized:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 import metatrader as mt4
----> 2 import tensortrade as tt
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import pandas as pd

File c:\Users\Zemaarij\miniconda3\envs\RL-bot\lib\site-packages\tensortrade\__init__.py:5
      3 from . import data
      4 from . import feed
----> 5 from tensortrade.oms import (
      6     orders,
      7     wallets,
      8     instruments,
      9     exchanges,
     10     services
     11 )
     12 from . import env
     13 from . import stochastic

File c:\Users\Zemaarij\miniconda3\envs\RL-bot\lib\site-packages\tensortrade\oms\orders\__init__.py:7
      4 from tensortrade.oms.orders.order_listener import OrderListener
      5 from tensortrade.oms.orders.order_spec import OrderSpec
----> 7 from tensortrade.oms.orders.create import (
...
   (...)
     21     iNaT,
     22 )

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...


Any suggestions would be appreciated.
I have tried upgrading the TensorTrade Python Library. I have consulted with AIs like Bard and ChatGPT. I have also Googled it but I am not getting any explicit answer. Please help!
```